# Уникальные максимальные значения в словаре

Tags: python, dict

Как оставить в словаре только уникальные максимальные значения?

```
import re
def checkio(text: str) -> str:
    # replace this for solution
    text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',text)
    text_low = text.lower()
    text_split = re.findall(r'\D', text_low)
    result = []
    alpha = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(text_split)-1):
        if text_split[i]==text_split[i+1]:
            count = count+1
        result.append(count)
    for i in text_split:
        if i!=' ':
            alpha.append(i)
    res_dict = dict(zip(alpha, result))
    list_d_v = list(res_dict.items())
    list_d_v.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)# отсортированный словарь по значениям
    # далее необходимо в данном словаре оставить только максимальные значения и произвести сортировку по ним
    # по алфавиту и вывести полученное значение с максимальным значением значения и первое по алфавиту
    return #


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(checkio("Hello World!"))

    # These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert checkio("Hello World!") == "l", "Hello test"
    assert checkio("How do you do?") == "o", "O is most wanted"
    assert checkio("One") == "e", "All letter only once."
    assert checkio("Oops!") == "o", "Don't forget about lower case."
    assert checkio("AAaooo!!!!") == "a", "Only letters."
    assert checkio("abe") == "a", "The First."
    print("Start the long test")
    assert checkio("a" * 9000 + "b" * 1000) == "a", "Long."
    print("The local tests are done.")
```

Comment: Согласна, извините, сейчас все приму.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы не изобретать велосипед можно воспользоваться [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def checkio(text: str) -> str:
    text = sorted(re.sub(r"[\W\d]", "", text.lower()))
    res = Counter(text).most_common(1)
    if res:
        return res[0][0]
    return None


assert checkio("Hello World!") == "l", "Hello test"
assert checkio("How do you do?") == "o", "O is most wanted"
assert checkio("One") == "e", "All letter only once."
assert checkio("Oops!") == "o", "Don't forget about lower case."
assert checkio("AAaooo!!!!") == "a", "Only letters."
assert checkio("abe") == "a", "The First."
print("Start the long test")
assert checkio("a" * 9000 + "b" * 1000) == "a", "Long."
print("The local tests are done.")
```

---

Тесты:

```
In [30]: %paste
assert checkio("Hello World!") == "l", "Hello test"
assert checkio("How do you do?") == "o", "O is most wanted"
assert checkio("One") == "e", "All letter only once."
assert checkio("Oops!") == "o", "Don't forget about lower case."
assert checkio("AAaooo!!!!") == "a", "Only letters."
assert checkio("abe") == "a", "The First."
print("Start the long test")
assert checkio("a" * 9000 + "b" * 1000) == "a", "Long."
print("The local tests are done.")

## -- End pasted text --
Start the long test
The local tests are done.
```

Comment: Чтобы исключить еще и все числа нужно добавить                                                                          
    text = sorted(re.sub(r"[\W\d]", "", text.lower()))

Comment: @jokop, я этого не увидел в тестах, поэтому не удалял числа. Сейчас исправил в ответе...